# Are there optimization methods for k-NN parameter $k$?

Tags: optimization, k-nearest-neighbour

Currently I am just go through from the min to the max, and determine $k$ by the performance. I am wondering if there's optimization approaches for selecting $k$? I am aware of there's question in this site asking for a practical method for selecting $k$, but I would like to know **if there's any optimization strategy works for k-NN?** **My objective is make it more time efficient.**

When I combine k-NN with another approach (with one parameter: ki) for a specific application, I found the objective function seems not smooth with respect to the two parameters: $ki$ and $item Neighborhood size$ ($k$). (See the pic)

**How about the following method:** I assume there are local maxima values of $k$.

In a case where I have the possible values of k between  [1, 1000].

1. I make a step size $s=$ 20, and then there will be 50 first-round $k$ values = {1, 20, 40,...,1000}. I evaluate them and get the results.
2. for each first-round $k$ values, I produce 50 second-round $k$ values by adding $s/2==10$. Then I will have second-round $k$ values={$10,30,50,...,900$}. Then I evaluate them and get the results.
3. I think in this way I can get a rough outline of the relation between performance and parameter $k$, and then next I can determine a most wanted range of $k$, then I can use a much smaller step size $s_2$ to continue the aforementioned process.

**Does this method fall into the category of Monte Carlo methods?**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either cross validation(k-fold cross-validation) or brute force using methods such as grid search

See this paper:http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rahuls/pub/icml2000-rahuls.pdf

and this one on grid search for details: http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume13/bergstra12a/bergstra12a.pdf